# How do I use VBA DateAdd on selected cells only

Tags: excel, vba

Hope someone can help please, I am using the below code to add a year to dates in column A, whilst this works perfectly as is, I would like to only apply this change to the date based on the contents of column B. eg if cell B4 has Yes then add 1 year to the date in A4 etc, just cant seem to work the logic through to check the contents of B to change A within this loop. thanks. Kevin

```
Sub DateChange()
Dim r As Range
With Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
 For Each r In .Cells
 If IsDate(r.Value) Then
 r.Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, r.Value)
 End If
 Next
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check each cell in column B using [`Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset).

If `r` corresponds to `A4`, then `r.Offset(,1)` corresponds to `B4`, and so on.

```vb
If IsDate(r.Value) And r.Offset(,1).Value = "Yes" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

If only there was a way to handle structured data, best based on criterias ;)

Oh there is sth. called SQL and surprise, you can [use Excel sheets as tables and query them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee692882(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)!

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub addOneYearToFirstColIfSecondContainsYes()
Dim cn as Object
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim cmd as Object
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")


cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=No"";"
      
Set Cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

Cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [sheet1$] SET [F1]=Dateadd('yyyy',1,[F1]) WHERE [F2] = 'Yes';"
Cmd.Execute
End Sub
```

Compared to a foreach loop through a range, as fast as lightning. Of course you should store your data in a database (Excel is **not** a database) where execution would be far more performant (not talking about data security and integrity) and fetch the data using a data connection